# Prove sequence $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} $ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I will prove in two ways.Please point the mistake for each method

*the problem doesn't give the limit value

First

$$\left ( \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \right )^{2}< \epsilon ^{2} $$

$$ \frac{4}{n}<\epsilon ^{2}$$

$$\frac{4}{\epsilon ^{2}} < n$$

Then the inequality $\frac{4}{n}< \epsilon ^{2} \Rightarrow  \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}< \epsilon $also hold the sequence converge to some number

Second

if$S_{n}$ converge to some number for $\epsilon > 0$

then

$ \left |S_{n}-L   \right |< \epsilon $ for every $n> $

$$ \left (\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}  \right )^{2}< \epsilon ^{2}$$

$$ \frac{4}{n}< \epsilon ^{2}$$

$$ \frac{4}{\epsilon ^{2}}< n$$

We choose $N\geq \frac{4}{\epsilon ^{2}}$

then

$$n> N\geq \frac{4}{\epsilon ^{2}}$$

therefore $\left |S_{n}  \right |< \epsilon $ for every n> $N$

Comment: Are you obliged to always use epsilon and delta? I think a lot of these problems can be knocked off together (its what I did as an undergraduate).

Comment: no I mean $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$ as I wrote

Comment: @Alephnull I just read one-fourth of sequence chapter in real analysis book I try to think another way to solve this problem,but I have no idea.

Comment: Prove or disprove: the product of convergent sequences is convergent, the reciprocal of a convergent sequence is convergent, monotone increasing sequences are convergent, a sequence is convergent iff its subsequences all converge to the same point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is monotone. Its subsequence denoted by $n_k=k^2$ converges.